# Can't get LIKE query to return both 2 and 4 digit year results for records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with a column for "year" and the values currently stored are both 2 and 4 digits for each year, such as "18" and "2018".

I am trying to use LIKE to return records for both the 18 and 2018 where the user chooses "2018" for year in the html form.

So far, using the below approach, it only returns values for 2018 and not values where year data is stored just as "18"

I can see it passing "2018" value as it should in the URL and again, it works fine for returning results matching 2018.

Here is the full query:

```
$year = $_GET['year'];

$query = "(
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE ('$name' IS NULL OR '$name' = '' OR name = '$name')
AND ('$city' IS NULL OR '$city' = '' OR city = '$city') AND ('$state' IS NULL 
OR '$state' = '' OR state = '$state') AND ('$county' IS NULL OR '$county' 
= '' OR county = '$county') AND ('$year' IS NULL OR '$year' = '' 
OR year LIKE '%$year%') AND ('$month' IS NULL OR '$month' = '' OR
month = '$month')order by name)";
```

Comment: You are doing somewhere wrong, it must work, see https://ibb.co/ghRdHc

Comment: @Mr.Anonymous Well, I can't specify to match '18' like in your example because it is a dynamic variable being pulled in as a year (2018 in this case). Maybe it can't find an 18 pattern out of 4 digits when dynamically passed somehow?

Comment: recheck your code. try printing your MySQL query before executing to see what query is really being sent to MySQL server

Comment: If you search for `18` **and** `2018` then use `year IN(18, 2018)`

Comment: Just posted full query. Paul....I can't specify 18,2018 because the user can select any year such as 2021, in which case the variable being passed to the query is 2021.

Comment: Use PHP to get 18 out of 2018: `$yy = $yyyy % 100`. Or `$yy = $yyyy - 2000`

Comment: I think you are missing the goal. A user chooses a  year from an html form. Then that year is passed to a search page. If no year is chose, they see all results. If a year like 2019 is choose, I want to see all records matching 2019 or 19. I don't know what number will be passed to the code though. The variable is dynamic--choosen by the user.

Comment: What did I miss? `$year = 2018; $yy = $year % 100; $query = "... year IN($year, $yy) ...";`

Comment: What is stored in `$_GET['year']`? Is it 18 or 2018?

Comment: 2020 is stored. or 2019 or 2018. Whatever year they pick as a 4 digit year. I think I will just do everything as 2 digits though and skip the issue altogether....

Comment: So you consider 1800, 1180, and 2018, all to be valid results ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$year = 18;
select * from test where year LIKE '$year%'; //OUTPUTS YEAR STARTS WITH 18
select * from test where year LIKE '%$year'; //OUTPUTS YEAR ENDS WITH 18
select * from test where year LIKE '%$year%'; //OUTPUTS YEAR WITH PATTERN OF 18
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I found too but it still just returns the 2018 results when I use the %$year pattern, which is the one i want. I am pulling the $year value from another page using GET and there is no issue. It works for 2018 but still not giving results for 18

Comment: My query is a little more complex that i first shared. I edited the question but i don't think it matters..

Comment: @ jerome thanks but still just giving results of 2018 and no rows where 18 is there no matter what. Yet the code works fine in all other ways...

Answer (score 0):

You can "normalize" the `year` with `year % 100 + 2000`. So if you search for `2018`, the condition would be

```
year % 100 + 2000 = 2018
```

This will match both: `year = 18` and `year = 2018`. But also `year = 118`.

Note that `NULL` will be converted to an empty string in PHP. So something like `'$name' IS NULL` will never happen. And you can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE '$name'   IN ('', name)
  AND '$city'   IN ('', city)
  AND '$state'  IN ('', state)
  AND '$county' IN ('', county)
  AND '$year'   IN ('', year % 100 + 2000)
  AND '$month'  IN ('', month)
order by name
```

And you should use a prepared statement with placeholders instead of injecting unsafe variables into the query string.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that your user selects 2018 and you're using like for 2018 only as your code suggests:

$year = $_GET['year'];

I'll suggest you to pass right 2 characters to $year variable here only and it'll good to go.

Comment: Lol. I'm not sure that warrants a correct answer but it is what I just decided to do. I am converting everything to 2 digits since 4 is unnecessary anyway for my website. Just need to clean my date a bit

Answer (score 0):

Your data is simply broken. You should have normalised the data before storing it in the database.

### Preparing for Storage

It is somewhat ok, if you want your users to have some freedom on input. However, you don't have that luxury on the database. To repair the user input, you can use a function / method:

```
function normaliseYear(int $year): int
{
    if (999 < $year && $year < 10000) {
        // Year is already normalised
        return $year;
    }

    if (0 <= $year && $year < 100) {
        // Got the year within the century, assume 21. century
        return 2000 + $year;
    }

    // You can put other repairable cases here

    // Got something we can not repair
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Unable to normalise $year as a year");
}
```

You use this function / method both on data creation and retrieval, so your database is clean and the queries stay simple (=fast).

### Reparing the Storage

Since you already have 'bad' data in your database, you need to repair it. Actually, you need to do the same normalisation on the existing data, but fortunately only once.

```
UPDATE test SET year = 2000 + year WHERE year < 100;
```

### Querying

Your query will then look like

```
$year = ($year === '' || $year === null) ? null : normaliseYear((int)$_GET['year']);

// Do not forget to sanitise user input!
$month = (int)$month;
// ...

$skipName   = empty($name) ? 1 : 0;
$skipCity   = empty($city) ? 1 : 0;
$skipState  = empty($state) ? 1 : 0;
$skipCounty = empty($county) ? 1 : 0;
$skipYear   = ($year === null) ? 1 : 0;
$skipMonth  = empty($month) ? 1 : 0;

$query = "(
    SELECT * 
    FROM test
    WHERE ($skipName OR name = '$name')
      AND ($skipCity OR city = '$city')
      AND ($skipState OR state = '$state')
      AND ($skipCounty OR county = '$county')
      AND ($skipYear OR year = $year)
      AND ($skipMonth OR month = $month)
    ORDER BY name
)";
```